# How to initiate multiple Gecko browsers/instances [each with own 'environment'] in one application?

Tags: c#, proxy, http-proxy, gecko, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX since a few days and it works really nice. I am automating a tedious process that has to download web pages, analyse them, process, and send a few messages back and forth (most websites use socket.io for this), and cleanly close the connection. Though some website limit 1 socket io connection per IP. I wanted to see if a proxy would work but whenever I use the documentation way of setting the Gecko http proxy, it sets the proxy for all `GeckoBrowser` instances, but I need a different proxy per instance.

The obvious solution would be to put the code into multiple proccesses and launch that, but the jobs need to communicate with each other aswell to exchange information, and this is very difficult using multiple processes. Getting the html content, controlling the controls in other processes etc is alot more work to do from 1 main process which spawns children processes, compared to one application initiating more browsers and having all the needed controls.

Is there an easier way to set per-instance http proxy in Gecko?